# Proof complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to prove this:
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\alpha^n = \displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2}$ if $|\alpha | < 1$

I think this is a geometric series, and i have to solve it with a limit but don't know how to raise it

Comment: It's not a geometric series...

Comment: Divide both sides by $\alpha$ and then integrate both sides of what you get with respect to $\alpha$. This of course requires $\alpha \neq 0$, but when you find the final expression, you can differentiate at $\alpha=0$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568701/power-series-representation-calculation) for a solution technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha}, \quad |\alpha| < 1.$$
Now, complex power series can be differentiated term-wise (see [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Complex_Power_Series) for justification). Thus, differentiating both sides of the above equation we find that
$$1 + 2\alpha + 3\alpha^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{(1 - \alpha)^2}, \quad |\alpha| < 1.$$
If we multiply both sides by $\alpha$, we obtain:
$$\alpha + 2\alpha^2 + 3\alpha^3 + \cdots = \frac{\alpha}{(1 - \alpha)^2}, \quad |\alpha| < 1.$$